# Could not load file or assembly SQLite.Net, Version=3.1.0.0

Tags: javascript, c#, sqlite, uwp, winjs

I'm working on **C# UWP** project for **Windows 10 Desktop Applications**,
all  **SQLite**. Functionality implemented in Windows runtime and windows class library then attach windows runtime references to **Win Js** project up to working fine. While I'm  trying calling those methods create a database, insert records into JavaScript applications getting below error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'SQLite.Net, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL). If so, you need to install the `SQLite support for UWP`. You can find it by `Universal Windows Platform` section of [This Page](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL).

After reinstalling the `Vsix` file, restart your visual studio and add reference  to your RuntimeComponent by `add reference->Universal Windows->Extensions->SQLite for Universal Windows Platform`.

If the problem still persists, you can try remove the nuget package and add the dll references directly. There are two dlls you need to reference. You can find them under:

1. `C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\SQLite.Net.Core-PCL\3.1.1\lib\portable-win8+net45+wp8+wpa81+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\SQLite.Net.dll`
2. `C:\Users\v-xucxia.FAREAST\.nuget\packages\SQLite.Net-PCL\3.1.1\lib\portable-win81+wpa81\SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.dll`

Comment: Thank you, Elvis,  yes I am using SQLite.Net-PCL I am not tried with the first process I tried with the second process finally it's working fine